# Why is tan(Math.PI) returning a wrong value?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I'm just wondering why is this line

```
MessageBox.Show(Math.Tan(Math.PI).ToString());
```

returning value = -1.22460635382238E-16 , shouldn't that be 0 ? or am I missing something here ?

Comment: `int x = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Tan(Math.PI));`. It is. Just rounding, as in the duplicate.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the truncated value of `Tan` to be much use as evidence here.

Comment: Still a bit confused but should check back some old school math I guess :-). Thanks mates.

Comment: The problem is `Math.PI` does not equal `π`. It is `3.14159265358979323846`. Because it is not ***exactly*** `π`, `Math.Tan(3.14159265358979323846)` is not 0. Also, tags should not be in the title, also I corrected the title as you are working with `Math.PI` not `180`.

Comment: Meh, Math.Tan() also can never produce a result that is accurate to more than 15 digits.  Technically the roundoff error in Math.PI could be opposite of the roundoff error in Math.Tan() and you'd get a happy result.  Low odds for that of course.  The assumption that the result is not correct is just wrong.